# Meaning of Two fields in Summary Report from JMeter - Test and Total

Tags: jmeter, report, listener, summary

In the Summary report of the Jmeter, there are two fields at the end of the report.
The names of the fields are Test and Total,
Can someone please explain to me what is the meaning of that two fields?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `Test` is something you define, either a [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) or [Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/JMeter-Transaction-controller-behavior) label
2. [JMeter metrics](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) like Average, Min, Max, etc. are calculated per-sampler-label, the `TOTAL` field contains cumulative information for ALL samplers which the Listener was able to catch.